# sql multiply column from another column sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, multiplication

i need to multiply a column value with another column value and then find the total sum

```
SubjectTable

SubjectMarksId SubjectCode Marks

1                  4ww      50
2                  8qw      50
3                  7uy      50

MarksType

MarksTypeId MarksType  StudentCount Marks
1            Sports        1        10
2            Math          1        10
3            English       1        1
4            Physics       1        10  // Marks sum(10+10+1*50+10) multiply condition, where  MarksTypeId=3 with SubjectCode = 8qw in SubjectTable
```

here is how i tried to multiply

```
select StudentMark*(SELECT  Marks  AS SubjectMark
FROM    SubjectTable
WHERE   SubjectCode = '8qw')
from
(
SELECT  Marks  AS StudentMark
FROM    MarksType
WHERE   MarksTypeId= '3'

) src
```

finally below is sum total, it is working fine , but how to multiply another column value then find total sum ?

```
SELECT Student.StudentId, Student.Name, sum(MarksType.Marks) as  TotalMarks
FROM
MarksType
INNER JOIN
MarksDetails on MarksType.MarksTypeId = MarksDetails.MarksTypeId
INNER  JOIN 
Student on Student.StudentId =  MarksDetails.StudentId

group by Student.Name,Student.StudentId
```

any help would be great.

```
     UPDATE:
```

the table details was less provide because of situation , so the output was wrong, anyway thanks to @Darka and Piyush. next time from my side details will be provided in clear way, if requested i can delete this question by help of moderators. Cause this may effect others folks research.

Comment: Not clear how `SubjectTable` related with `MarksType`? And how `MarksDetails ` looks like?

Comment: what I mean is that why MarksTypeId= '3' must be multiplied and other not...? How to know?

Comment: @stom:- I think, your approach is totally wrong, you are not giving table information and relationship those are in your query.   You got better solution, if you provide tables struture with Sample Data, and expected output. because what you written in your question is very much unclear and its hard to find logic behind this

Answer (score 1):

You can do maths inside the SUM function, i.e.

```
SUM(Column1 * Column2) as Result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT SUM(MT.Marks * ISNULL(T.Marks,1))
FROM MarksType AS MT
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT ST.Marks 
                FROM SubjectTable AS ST 
                WHERE ST.SubjectCode = '8qw' AND MT.MarksTypeId= 3
            ) AS T(Marks)
```

And the last `SUM` can be like this (just guessing as no data provided):

```
SELECT Student.StudentId, Student.Name, sum(MT.Marks * ISNULL(T.Marks,1)) as  TotalMarks
FROM MarksType AS MT
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT ST.Marks 
                FROM SubjectTable AS ST 
                WHERE ST.SubjectCode = '8qw' AND MT.MarksTypeId= 3
            ) AS T(Marks)
INNER JOIN MarksDetails 
    on MT.MarksTypeId = MarksDetails.MarksTypeId
INNER JOIN Student 
    on Student.StudentId =  MarksDetails.StudentId
group by Student.Name,Student.StudentId
```

Comment: if OP not provided data why are you guessing, let him provide the data. and still why only multiply with MarksTypeId 3, question is very much unclear

Comment: yeap agreed, but that what he said: multiply only MarksTypeId = 3. Can't say it is wrong :D